# Best way to implement SQLite data storage in AIR

Tags: sqlite, air, data-binding

What would be the best way to commit data to an SQLite database in AIR? I currently have an NamesCollection class which extends ArrayCollection. The addItem method takes the name as a parameter and passes it on to the addItem method of the base class, then writes it to the database using the flash.data.* API.

I would also like to use data binding with this collection and a datagrid.

Is there a better way to do this? I've googled this a bit but couldn't find too many useful working examples.